# AS3 variable protected functions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class

I know that I can create a class and then all my variables will be protected. Then I can insert functions inside this class. But to use these functions I would have to create an object of my class. I don't want to. I want only to use the functions, and they must be variable protected, and importable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to instantiate ("create an object") a class to use it's functions you can make your functions `static`.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static function myFunction(){
        trace("yada!");
    }
}

// You call it this way
MyClass.myFunction();
```

What do you mean with "variable protected" and "importable"?

Comment: Do I still need 'package'?

Comment: Yes, and also you will need to import the class depending if it's your project folder or not.